# Thunderbird, Alt+Tab Text Disappears

Tags: thunderbird, text

Whole message lines disappear in the Thunderbird 38.8.0 mail client on Lubuntu 16.04.

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher shows icons, but shows no text. So the problem is likely not specifically with Thunderbird, though Thunderbird is the only app that exhibits the problem.

It looks like this (I've whited out most of the columns for privacy, but you can see the issue in terms of lines that have *no* text):

[image: Thunderbird with missing text]

Closing Thunderbird and reopening resolves the problem **until** the next time
the computer is put to sleep and wakes up again. Only other programs running are `google-chrome-stable` and `sublime-text-3`. The problem does not occur 100% of the time.

Running from the command line did not generate any useful debugging information.

Comment: I have tried this on my machine, and I am not getting the issue.  Can you give more detail, maybe what version of Ubuntu you are running, what other programs are running while this is happening, look up your memory usage when this happens, what version of Thunderbird are you on.  Things like that.

Comment: Added Ubuntu and Thunderbird versions, plus other programs running. Sorry for not doing that in the original post.

Comment: Just so you know, and this is not documented per se, I have found on some of my machines, not all, what feels like a memory leak in Chrome stable/and chromium.  I find it annoying but have not done anything about it.  Does this happen if you only run thunderbird by itself, basically reboot the machine and run it all by itself, do not run Chrome, do this for however long you might normally to see the issue, then put the machine to sleep and try it.  just to see if the problem still happens.

Comment: @ChristopherAngulo-Bertram: I can't test that today, but can try. Again: there's always been plenty of memory available when this problem arises.

Comment: Just FYI:  https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/86yzpxX7aws  after test just try using firefox, and see if it goes away.